# Best algorithm to interpolate on a grid

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

I have a set points whose coordinates are given by the arrays `x`, `y` and `z` and the value of the density field in each point is stored in the array `d`.
I would like to reconstruct the density field on a uniform grid. What's the best algorithm to do that?
I know that in python, the scipy module come in handy with the `griddata` function but I would like to write my own code, I just need a hint.

Comment: Do you have a grid, or a random scattering of points? How are your points stored?

Comment: my points are randomly distributed, they're not defined on any kind of grids. The point is to smooth the density distribution on a regular mesh.

Comment: Then [this](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/19/2/178.full.pdf) may be of some help to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some sort of scalar field and the points are the origins of the field, you can implement a brute force approach by walking all lattice points and calculating the field intensity given the sources. There are both recursive methods that allow "blanking" wide volumes where the field is more or less constant, and techniques to save some CPU time by calculating the variations from one point to the next.

If the points you have are samplings of a value, then you will have to decompose your space in volumes and interpolate the values. You can employ a simple Voronoi decomposition - this is usually done in 2D for precipitation measurements - or a *Delaunay tetrahedralization* (you can look into [TetGen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/)'s documentation). The first approach assumes that the function is constant throughout each Voronoi volume; the last allows rendering a [trilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation).

If you need to smooth a 3D grid, the trilinear interpolation looks like the best approach.

There are also other methods used for fast visualization, that involve maintaining a list of 3D points in order of distance from any one given point in your regular grid. When moving through the grid, you recalculate distances using quadratic increments. Then, you perform a simple interpolation based on a subset of points of chosen cardinality (i.e., if you consider the four nearest points at distances d1..d4, you would calculate the value in P by proportionally weighing the values v1..v4). This approach is fast and easy to implement by yourself, but be warned that it underperforms wherever the minimum distance between points is less than the lattice step (you can compensate by considering more points where this happens; and the effect is less evident if the sampled function is smooth at the same scale).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a mathematical method yourself, you need to learn the theory, of course. In this case, it's **3D scattered data interpolation**.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#Irregular_grid_.28scattered_data.29), [MATLAB help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) and [scipy help](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) say there are at least half a dozen different methods. WP has a fairly good description of them and there's a [comparison article](http://www.unizar.es/acz/05Publicaciones/Monografias/MonografiasPublicadas/Monografia20/Monogr20-8Bozzini.pdf) but I strongly suggest you find something in your native language on such a terminology-intensive subject.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to form the Delaunay triangulation of the scattered points `[x,y,z]`, (actually a tetrahedralisation in your 3d case!) and perform interpolation within each element using a linear representation of the density field, defined at the tetrahedron vertices.

To evaluate the density at each structured grid point you would (i) determine which tetrahedron the point lay within and (ii) evaluate the linear interpolant.

Forming the Delaunay triangulation is non-trivial, put there are a few good libraries that can be used for this, depending on your language of choice. One good option is [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/).

Hope this helps.